# accessing movieclips within a movieclip from the main timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4, movieclip

Ok i have a mc called *dracoplay* and inside is another mc called *Drakep* and inside that there is another mc called *wing* and *head* as you may have guessed they make up a dragon. So *dracoplay* is the character that gets coded, it moves, breathes fire, etc. etc. *Drakp* is the body and the *head* and *wing* have animations. I have one problem i have no clue whatsoever how to make access *Drakep*/*head*/*wing* from the main timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access children directly through dot notation like so:

dracoplay.Drakep.head

dracoplay.Drakep.wing

Assuming that "Drakep", "head", and "wing" are instance names and not library asset names. If they are library asset names, then give those clips instance names and use those instance names to access them.